# Writing my own script to resolve a git conflict at merge time

Tags: git, merge

### Question

Is there any way of writing a script which will hook into the merge process of git and will automatically resolve the following merge conflict at merge time?

### Scenario

We have a file version-controlled by git, which (among other things) contains definitions which must all have incrementing integer values.

```
MY_CONSTANT = 0xB;
ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 0xC;
```

This file is often edited by multiple developers at the same time, and it's a pain to merge:

Developer 1 adds:

```
DEV1_CONSTANT = 0xD;
```

Developer 2 adds:

```
DEV2_CONSTANT = 0xD;
```

When merged, we actually want the file to look like:

```
MY_CONSTANT = 0xB;
ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 0xC;
DEV1_CONSTANT = 0xD;
DEV2_CONSTANT = 0xE;
```

(The last line has changed to ***0xE***.)

However, git produces a merge conflict (as expected). I would like conflicts on this file to be resolved automatically instead.

Comment: Note that the actual constant values don't matter (so I'd be happy with the merged file ending up as DEV2_CONSTANT = 0xD and DEV1_CONSTANT = 0xE).

Comment: Maybe you can write a merge driver, an example here: https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [githook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) document. Read the description of `post-merge` hook:

> This hook cannot affect the outcome of git merge and is not executed, if the merge failed due to conflicts.

In current version of git, there is no something like `merge-conflict-hook`.

However, you can still implement your own script to handle this problem. The pseudo code might be like:

```
system('git fetch origin master')
status = system('git merge origin/master')
if status!=0 && check_enum_conflict()
  resolve_enum_conflict()
end
```

The actual implementation will be quite complex. You need to:

1. Write a script to execute git commands.
2. Check the result of merge. See if the enum file is conflicted.
3. Parse the enum file and try to resolve the conflict programmatically.
4. Handle every possible cases. Ex. What if other file also conflicts?

This will be really complex work. Do it if you think it worth.

Answer (score 0):

No version control system can resolve these conflicts automatically because it can't know that the values don't matter anywhere.

It sounds to me like you don't care which value is assigned to each constant as long as they are different and incrementing. Did you consider using an enum for these constants and let the compiler assign the values of the enum constants at compile time?

I would like to post an example, but you didn't mention which programming language you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp. I know that the version control system can't resolve the conflict automatically - that's why I want to know whether it's possible to write my own script and hook into git's merge process.

The file is much more complicated than the example I gave above and changing its implementation is, I'm afraid, not possible. There are hundreds of files on our project which depend on its current structure.